# Using a conditional in logstash

Tags: logstash

Has anyone ever added a conditional to an input? I'm using various versions of the beats plugin. Versions less than 7.11 don't have @metadata I'd like to use two different indicies conditionally. For example,

```
15    beats {
16         port => "5000"
17         codec => "plain"
18         ssl => true
19         ssl_certificate_authorities => ["/etc/pki/logstash/logstashCA.pem"]
20         ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/logstash/logstashCA.pem"
21         ssl_key => "/etc/pki/logstash/logstashCA.p8"
22         ssl_verify_mode => "force_peer"
23         if [version] not in [beat] {
24                 add_field => { "target_index" => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[beat]}-7-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" }
25         }
26         add_field => { "target_index" => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[beat][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" }
27    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot have a conditional based on fields of the event in an input because at the time the input is built no events exit. However you can do it in the filter section

```
if [beat][version] {
    add_field => { "target_index" => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[beat][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" }
} else {
    add_field => { "target_index" => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[beat]}-7-%{+YYY
}
```